# Optional Parameter vs Empty Parameter Methods and Constructor with Overloading

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

To put it simply, say you have two methods:

```
public static void WriteMessage() 
{
    Console.Write("Empty Parameter Function");
}



public static void WriteMessage(string data = "Some Data")
{
    Console.Write("Optional Parameter Function");
}
```

Why is it that if you call the WriteMessage function without any parameters, it runs the "Empty Parameter Function"? I understand method overloading, but why does not the optional parameter function run as if the empty parameter function didn't exist, it would run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following point regarding **Overload Resolution**, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx), explains that decision:

> If two candidates are judged to be equally good, preference goes to a candidate that does not have optional parameters for which arguments were omitted in the call. This is a consequence of a general preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer parameters.

Comment: And also because this way, adding a method overload with an optional parameter would not change the behavior of existing code, which would be rather unexpected.